# LibreOffice Calc , Some spreadsheet data is randomly ignored when converting to a dictionary using openpyxl

Tags: dictionary, duplicates, openpyxl, libreoffice

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# MAKE DICTIONARY FROM SPREADSHEET
workbook = load_workbook('Zonebreakers3col.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.active

for value in sheet.iter_rows(values_only = True):
    print(value)

data_dict = {} # make an empty dictionary
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True): # row 2 position[1] starts the actual data (row 1 is [0])
     header = row[0] # [0] is FIRST column HEADER NAME, WITH EACH ITERATION ROW[1] WOULD BE BREAKER
     breaker_data = {
         'ZONE' : row[0], # if in square brackets, then 0 is the first column which is ZONE.
         'BREAKER' : row[1], # row[1] indicates the second column location, BREAKER
         'APPLIANCE' : row[2]
         }
     print(row) # all spreadsheet data printed
     data_dict[header] = breaker_data
print(f'dictionary produced. {data_dict}\n')

# ONLY 16 OUT OF 39 KEY\VALUE PAIRS ARE PRODUCED
# How to get the all of the dictionary output.
```

```
  >   ZONE            BREAKER       APPLIANCE 
  > ------------------------------------------
   > attic              1           roof fans
   > basement           1           sump pump
   > garage             1           bench outlet
   > kitchen            2           counter outlets
    >foyer              3           ceiling lights
   > foyer              5           fan
   > outside           6_8          central air
   > attic              11          light
    >garage             9           wall outlet
   > office             13          tract light
   > main bathroom      2           outlet
```

representative sample of my spreadsheet which is an Excel 2007-365 format. I show duplicates in both ZONE AND BRREAKER columns. the conversion to dictionary excludes some duplicates and some single
entries but does loop from beginning to end of all 40 rows. omissions Seems random.
The dictionary prints to screen half complete and on one line. Formatted as a dictionary. I want to be able to access info in the dict in various ways but I have to first get a complete dictionary.

I populated a three-column spreadsheet with data showing what each breaker controls in my house.    Header Row: ZONE, BREAKER, APPLIANCE, example: kitchen, 5, microwave
The problem is even though I list ALL 40 rows of information on my spreadsheet, 16 out of 39 rows of data are possessed when converting to a dictionary. the rest are seemingly randomly ignored.

Comment: You probably have duplicates in the `ZONE` column. Can you share  (copy/paste) a small example with some random data _as text_ of matching your spreadsheet and add it to your question, please ? Also, can you include the expected format of your dictionnary `data_dict` ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Timeless alludes to; you can only have unique keys in a dictionary. So once 'attic' is used as a key subquent attempts to use it again will result in the previous value(s) being overwritten. Given your example data there would only be 8 Zones in the dictionary, being the number of unique zone values in the 11 entries.
 To manage all the entries, you need to create a dictionary of dictionaries where the key to each dictionary is the Zone and each Breaker/Appliance is contained in sub dictionary under that key.

See example code modified from your original;
It is not necessary to add the Zone in the sub dictionaries since that is the key as mentioned, therefore `breaker_data` is created with just `BREAKER` & `APPLIANCE`. Then when added to `data_dict` it's either added with the Zone as a new key if not already existing or appended if it is. This results in a dictionary like below;
You can see that the Zone 'attic' contains two sub dictionaries that hold the Breaker and Appliance values for the two entries in the data. Zone 'basement' has only one entry so there is just the one sub dictionary etc.

```
{
 'attic': [
    {'BREAKER': 1, 'APPLIANCE': 'roof fans'}, 
    {'BREAKER': 11, 'APPLIANCE': 'light'}
 ], 
 'basement': [
    {'BREAKER': 1, 'APPLIANCE': 'sump pump'}
 ]
}
```

Once all the entries have been added to `data_dict` you can then display the details as requred.
The example print out displays the data as shown;

```
Zone: Attic
BREAKER: 1, APPLIANCE: roof fans, 
BREAKER: 11, APPLIANCE: light, 
-------------
Zone: Basement
BREAKER: 1, APPLIANCE: sump pump, 
-------------
Zone: Garage
BREAKER: 1, APPLIANCE: bench outlet, 
BREAKER: 9, APPLIANCE: wall outlet, 
-------------
Zone: Kitchen

...

Zone: Office
BREAKER: 13, APPLIANCE: tract light, 
-------------
Zone: Main Bathroom
BREAKER: 2, APPLIANCE: outlet, 
-------------
```

Example Code

```
...
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):  # row 2 position[1] starts the actual data (row 1 is [0])
    header = row[0]  # [0] is FIRST column HEADER NAME, WITH EACH ITERATION ROW[1] WOULD BE BREAKER
    breaker_data = {
        ### No need to include the zone as it is the Dictionary Key 
        # 'ZONE': row[0],  # if in square brackets, then 0 is the first column which is ZONE.
        'BREAKER': row[1],  # row[1] indicates the second column location, BREAKER
        'APPLIANCE': row[2]
    }
    print(row)  # all spreadsheet data printed
    if header in data_dict:
        data_dict[header] += [breaker_data]
    else:
        data_dict[header] = [breaker_data]


### Print out the Appliances on Breaker per room
for zone, values in data_dict.items():
    print(f'Zone: {zone.title()}')
    for item in range(len(values)):
        for unit, data in values[item].items():
            print(f"{unit}: {data}, ", end='')
        if item < len(values)-1:
            print('')
        else:
            print('\n-------------')
```

----Alternative----
**Alternative display format**

```
for zone, values in data_dict.items():
    print(f'Zone: {zone.title()}')
    for item in range(len(values)):
        print(f"BREAKER: {values[item]['BREAKER']}; {values[item]['APPLIANCE']}")
    print("------------")
```

**Output**

```
Zone: Attic
BREAKER: 1; roof fans
BREAKER: 11; light
------------
Zone: Basement
BREAKER: 1; sump pump
...
```

Comment: thanks again. Your suggested solution works great.

Comment: I have a question regarding 'The example print out displays the data as shown' chart.  On the first Key\Value printout I would like to eliminate the word APPLIANCE and the comma before it. This way the value to key BREAKER would be the breaker number itself which is also the key to what the appliances are.

Comment: I have put an alternative output display, Not sure its what you mean exactly, it would probably be easier to show the preferred display by editing and adding this detail to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your alternative solution. It's what I was ideally trying to achieve. Now I get to play around with modifying my spreadsheet and then applying what you have shown me to make it work also. Youve really helped greatly , thanks